# Syntax error on completely correct SQL syntax

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, full-text-search, mariadb

I'm trying to do a simple full-text search on phpmyadmin

```
SELECT * FROM `productmeta` 
WHERE MATCH(`pn`,`field`,`value`) AGAINST('capaci*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

**Table Structure**

```
| pn  | field               | value    |
| 9281| desc                | capacitor|
| 9282| number of capacitors| 7        |
| 9283| voltage             | 75w      |
```

**Errors**

Unrecognized keywords

Unexpected Tokens

**Specs**

- Server: localhost via TCP/IP
- Server type: MariaDB
- Server version: 10.0.17-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
- Protocol version: 10
- phpMyAdmin: 4.5.2
- Database Engine: innoDB

Am I doing this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with the phpMyAdmin parser. It's reported at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11742 and updates/discussion will occur there.

Answer (score 0):

Full text search can only be done on fields with type char, varchar or text check that this is your case. Try double quotes on the keyword.

Comment: all are varchars and fulltext indexed and I also tried to double quotes the keyword, still the same

Comment: have you tried running the query directly on the terminal (not through phpmyadmin) doubt that is the problem though. I executed your query successfully after setting a test table with same fields.

Comment: yes and I tried it on a php script, which doesn't give me any result